# Why don't sand get deformed when someone walks on it?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science

My question is about the structure of sand. Namely, when we walk on the beach sand seems to be very hard to deform, since we push on it from 'above'. But if from another perspective it is also very easy to replace for example. My question is really about how can we explain that sand is so hard to deform when we walk on the beach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because the sand particles have sharp, angular surfaces. when you press down on them, these rough surfaces engage one another and after some point the entire mass under your foot becomes "locked" together and behaves as a solid object, even though it consists of tiny particles.

Comment: If you've been to the gulf coast of florida, where the sand is mixed with lots of ground up shells that form flat plates instead of sharp corners, you can see the difference. You sink in quite a bit and it can be very tiring to walk on.

Comment: in addition, there's the quicksand phenomenon, which upends the equation and creates entrainment- a topic I would like to write about here, having studied it close-up in arizona.